# c# - make public an object created inside a function

Tags: c#, .net, pcap, winpcap, pcap.net

How can I use the object "communicator" created in main(), in the callback function? The PacketCommunicator class doesn't have a constructor.

```
class Program
{
    //public static PacketCommunicator communicator = new PacketCommunicator(); - can't do this; PacketCommunicator constructor doesn't exist
    //public static PacketCommunicator communicator = null; - this gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PacketCommunicator communicator = selectedDevice.Open(...)
        communicator.ReceivePackets(0, PacketHandler);
    }

    // Callback function invoked by ReceivePackets for every incoming packet
    private static void PacketHandler(Packet packet)
    {
        communicator.SendPacket(packet);
    }
}
```

The library I'm using is [Pcap.Net](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/).
Basically, what I'm trying to do is to capture packets on one interface, perform NAT on them, and send them on another interface.

Comment: Use a lambda expression and a closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SLaks mentioned in the comments, you could use a lambda.  Then communicator would not lose scope.

```
communicator.ReceivePackets(
    0, (packet) => 
        {
           //processing code goes here...
           communicator.SendPacket(packet);
        });
```

The way that PCAP works with receive packets is to just put it in a continual loop, breaking when you hit a time when you want to close.

There is a nice [example of that here](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Capturing%20the%20packets%20without%20the%20callback), though they are just reporting on the packets, not sending them on as you appear to be.

In this example you would instantiate communicator thusly

```
PacketCommunicator communicator = selectedDevice.Open(...)
```

Comment: I need the callback function, because I need to capture every packet and I have to process them (NAT) before I send them.

Comment: @user1410908 check my edits, you can easily put any processing, or other method calls into your lambda.

Comment: Even with a lambda I still get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at "communicator.SendPacket(packet);" at runtime.

Comment: @user1410908 is it in a using statement?  If so, take it out.

Comment: communicator can't be null because receiving works, and the callback function it's called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44576/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-user1410908)